# Updating linked table in Google Slides API

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-slides-api

I see that there's a method for updating a linked Chart in a Slide (RefreshSheetsChartRequest), but in my presentation I have Tables pasted in from Google Sheets that are linked to data in a spreadsheet. I can update these manually by clicking the update buttons in the Slides UI, but is there a way to use the API to update all the linked tables in a sheet programmatically?

Comment: Not yet! Please file a [feature request](https://developers.google.com/slides/support#missing_features).

Comment: Just filed a feature request. Thanks Maurice

Answer (score 2):

The feature request for refresh()'ing tables has been sitting for about 20 months now.  Nevertheless, I found this workaround from the feature request on the [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64027131) page:

"If anyone is reading this who wants the feature, one solution is to create a "table chart" in your sheet, from your existing table (that you were trying to link/update). It doesn't allow you to copy and paste from Sheets to Slides, but within Slides if you go to Insert -> Chart -> From Spreadsheet, then choose your sheet and chart (table). You can then use app scripts to automatically update it, as you can with a chart." - From ad...@lovecrafts.com

Hope this helps !

Comment: See here for another workaround implemented in Google Apps Script (could be adapted to the Slides API): https://stackoverflow.com/a/68689251